# How to apply Conditional validation for form model in anugar2

Tags: angular, typescript

I dont want required validator for Addres if value of this.type is 2.

Here are my code for form validation:

```
buildForm() {
     this.orgForm = this.fb.group({
     Name: [this.addUpdateModel.Name,  [Validators.required]],
     Id: ['', [Validators.pattern(this.constant.positiveIntegers), Validators.maxLength(6)]],
     Address: [this.addUpdateModel.Address,  [Validators.required]],
     });

    this.orgForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));
    this.onValueChanged(); // (re)set validation messages now
}
```

Any clue????

Comment: `Address: [this.addUpdateModel.Address, [(this.type === 2 ? Validators.nullValidator : Validators.required)]]`

Answer (score 1):

**You can use setValidators() method of reactive form and reset the validator. in your case the code will be something like this:-**

** Whenever you get this.type==2 in that function set validator to null **

```
  if(this.type==2){
    this.orgForm.controls.Address.setValidators(null);
    this.orgForm.get('Address').updateValueAndValidity();
}
else{
    this.orgForm.controls.Address.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    this.orgForm.get('Address').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```